# ASP.NET MVC Model Data - Loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a strongly typed View which displays data from my model (which comes from a database table), such as:

Model.servicetype
Model.serviceid

All the fields within this model contain true or false values.

I simply wanted to loop through the Model and either replace the values of true and false, or create some sort of generic list and output the data from that.
[image]

Note this is only for display purposes, the user can't edit etc.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: It does not make much sense. Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... just create a `static` *extension* method and called for example `ToWord` in your Utilities class as

```
public static string ToWord(this bool value)
{
    return value ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

and then use:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.breakpads.ToWord()) %>
```

**P.S.** With all the simple Razor Views ... why are you using WebForm Views? Rzor is so much simpler! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= string.Join(string.Empty,
    ViewData
    .ModelMetadata
    .Properties
    .Where(x => x.ModelType == typeof(bool))
    .Select(x => new { 
                           Name = x.GetDisplayName(), 
                           Value = (bool)x.Model
                     })
    .Select(x => string.Format(@"
<tr>
    <td>{0}</td>
    <td>{1}</td>
</tr>",
        x.Name,
        Html.Encode(x.Value ? "Yes" : "No"))
        .ToArray()))                            
%>
```

*Note that the call to ToArray() is unnecessary in .NET 4.0*